# Configurando Virtual Hosts no Apache

Tags: apache

Estou tentando criar um virtualhost aqui na empresa, porém o mesmo não funciona. O engraçado é que criei da mesma forma de outros virtualhosts que estão funcionando normalmente.

Segue exemplo abaixo:

VirtualHost 1

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName manobra.henriquestefani.com.br
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/bpm/intranet"
</VirtualHost>
```

VirtualHost 2

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName retornoviagem.henriquestefani.com.br
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs/retornoviagem"
</VirtualHost>
```

O virtualhost1 funciona normalmente, enquanto o virtualhost2 não.

Comment: Verifique se não está faltando colocar o novo host no arquivo `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Rodrigo no meu arquivo etc/hosts tem apenas esta linha.
127.0.0.1        localhost

Na verdade estou entrando agora na empresa e não sei pq tem apenas isto, mas todos os vhs estão funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Esse host tem que estar no arquivo `/etc/hosts` da máquina onde estão os sites, e não a sua.

Comment: Você ativou os dois no apache? Como são duas pastas diferentes e uma funciona e a outra não, verifique a permissão. Aparece algum erro no log?

Comment: Sim ele está na máquina onde estão os sites.

Comment: Como faço para verificar a permissão?

Comment: @user5313 depende. Seu apache está no Windows ou Linux? Geralmente o usuário do apache já tem permissão de leitura e escrita no diretório htdocs e seu conteúdo. Acho que seria mais interessante você colocar o server.log num pastebin da vida...

Comment: Meu apache está no Windows.

Comment: http://www.pastebin.ca/2640564

Comment: @Oliver, você pode até dar uma conferida nas permissões do diretório que você definiu como virtual e se certificar que o usuário do apache tem privilégios de leitura e escrita, mas creio não ser esse o problema. Mas veja mesmo assim e bota ai nos comments.

Comment: Veja qualquer coisa se esse link ajuda: http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/artigo/Virtual-Host-com-Apache/

Comment: Qual a versão do apache?

Comment: A versão do apache é 2.2.

Respondendo a pergunta anterior, o usuário tem sim privilégios de leitura e escrita.

Comment: Não é necessário colocar no `/etc/hosts`. Tenho um apache com VirtualHosts aqui e nunca precisei colocar nada nele. Neste caso creio que o domínio mesmo esteja mal configurado no DNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na documentação do apache 2.2, disponível em https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html, tem-se o seguinte exemplo.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

 <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.domain.tld
 DocumentRoot /www/domain
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.otherdomain.tld
 DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain
 </VirtualHost>
```

Aparentemente, pela documentação, a diretiva NameVirtualHost é obrigatória, mas não vi ela no seu exemplo.

Quando o Apache recebe uma requisição apontando para um domínio desconhecido, ela é direcionado ao primeiro VirtualHosts da configuração. Então, como seu VirtualHosts2 nem abre a página, pode ser que o domínio não esteja apontando para o IP correto, também.

Answer (score 0):

É necessário **reiniciar o Apache** após mudar as configurações, para que tenham efeito.