# Como criar dominios locais para testar meus sites e aplicações?

Tags: windows, redirecionamento, dns, localhost

Para meus testes gostaria de criar um redirecionamento de um dominio qualquer para `localhost:porta` em computador local, em Windows.

Pensei que seria possível pelo arquivo hosts em

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

fazendo algo como:

```
localhost:8084 webtest.local
```

Mas ao tentar acessar, receber o erro de que não é possível acessar o site e listar os DNS´s

```
ipconfig /displaydns
```

Aparece:

```
webtest.local
----------------------------------------
O nome não existe.
```

Tentei atualizar um possível cache fazendo:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

E para complicar, precisaria que fosse para `localhost:8888`, por exemplo,  e não somente para `127.0.0.1:8888`.

Existe uma forma pouco dramática de fazer isso?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Se quer uma solução simples e pronta, para testes rápidos, vá direto ao final da pergunta

Não cabem especificações de porta no `hosts`, e não há funcionalidade nenhuma relacionada com redirecionamentos ou qualquer coisa mais complexa que um par de IPs x Nomes.

O `hosts` é apenas um "índice", simplesmente você fornece um nome e ele devolve um IP, nem mais, nem menos. As portas de qualquer maneira vão ter que ser digitadas no *browser* ao acessar o recurso, se diferentes do padrão.

A maior vantagem de você criar vários domínios locais para apontar para o `127.0.0.1` em IPV4 é justamente poder testar vários endereços independentes sem precisar de portas e nem de caminhos diferentes do caminho real da aplicação hospedada.

#### Configurando:

O arquivo HOSTS no Windows 7 e maiores fica em

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Nas distros Linux é comum que fiquem em

```
/etc/hosts
```

A sintaxe do HOSTS é essa:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 webtest.local
127.0.0.1 outroteste.local
```

Pode agrupar por assuntos se preferir organizar:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 webtest.local outroteste.local maisumteste.local
```

A porta você especifica no servidor web e ao acessar o endereço. Se quiser acessar sem colocar porta, precisa configurar o servidor para porta 80, que é o padrão quando omitida para HTTP, e 443 quando omitida para HTTPS

Se quiser redirecionamento de portas, precisa por um servidor atendendo na porta 80 local, que verifique os nomes e redirecione adequadamente com algum script seu, mas se é para fazer isso, compensa simplesmente já apontar os *Virtual Hosts* do servidor cada um para o diretório certo dos sites.

#### Relacionado:

> [Configurar mutiplos dominios para o mesmo site (arquivos diferentes) IIS WS2012](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/155531/70)

> [Configurando Virtual Hosts no Apache](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5889/70)

#### CORS

Uma vantagem de fazer isto é que além de tudo você passa a ter o controle sobre o CORS como teria com qualquer domínio convencional, o que não é garantido usando `localhost`, dependendo do *browser*.

Para saber mais sobre CORS:

> [Qual é o significado de CORS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145490/70)

#### Solução rápida usando serviço de terceiros

Se você quer controle sobre o que está fazendo, precisa dos passos mencionados acima, mas se quiser apenas fazer um teste rápido na máquina local, alguém fez a gentileza de criar um serviço de DNS em `lvh.me` que sempre aponta para a máquina local.

Então, sem configurar nada, você já pode sair usando este endereço:

```
http://lvh.me/
```

que ele já aponta para o endereço local.

E você pode testar mais de um domínios sem problemas:

```
http://jamestk.lvh.me/
http://stackoverflow.lvh.me/
http://qualquercoisa.lvh.me/
```

Só não recomendo para coisas mais definitivas, pois pode ser que um dia o endereço pare de funcionar.

Além disso, no HOSTS você pode apontar não só para `127.0.0.1`, pode apontar para um IP da rede local e configurar várias máquinas da rede para o mesmo endereço, o que não é possível neste caso aqui.

Para especificar os IPs, uma alternativa boa é o [`xip.io`](http://xip.io). Em vez de você usar o endereço base, você inclui o IP que deseja como parte do endereço:

```
http://nomequeeuquiser.10.0.0.1.xip.io
```

ou simplesmente

```
http://10.0.0.1.xip.io
```

que, como se pode imaginar, vai resolver para o endereço `10.0.0.1`. Para usar qualquer outro endereço, basta ajustar o URL como desejar.

Answer (score 0):

O Problema é a porta!

Retire a porta do arquivos hosts:

De: `localhost:8084 webtest.local`

Para: `127.0.0.1 webtest.local`

Na hora de acessar pelo navegador volte a utilizar a porta:

http://webtest.local:8084

Comment: A respsota está igual a do @Bacco, gostaria de dar mais detalhes?