# PHP Access-Control-Allow-Origin - CORS - Localhost

Tags: php, ionic, cors, localhost

Estou tentando acessar uma aplicação localhost por uma outra aplicação que está também local, mas em outro IP e porta e não consigo de jeito nenhum. Já tentei de todas as formas e sempre aparece a mesangem de erro:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/suaapp/ws/customer/new. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.1.4:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

Estou usando o **Code Igniter** no PHP e a aplicação é em **Ionic**.

Comment: Vê se algum destes links ajudam: https://www.google.pt/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=codeigniter%20cors

Comment: Tenta colocar isso no início do seu código PHP: `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');`

Comment: Sim. Eu acabei de testar enviando para um servidor e funcionou. O que eu devo fazer para funcionar localhost? Tem alguma segurança a mais?

Comment: Crie uma entrada de domínio no hosts, que você pode passar a usar o CORS normalmente: [Como criar dominios locais para testar meus sites e aplicações?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/170812/70)

Comment: adicionei no Hosts para direcionar para phpdev.local:8080 e continua dando o mesmo erro de CORS.